# Laravel - Relationships issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 models:

```
class Site extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }
    public function stats()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Stat');
    }
}

class User extends Model
{
    public function sites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Site');
    }
    public function stats()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Stat');
    }
}

class Stat extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
    }
    public function sites()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Site');
    }
}
```

So there are :

- a many to many relation between sites and users
- a many to many relation between users and stats
- a one to many relation between site and stats

A site have a list of stats and from this list, an user can have some stats.

[image]

I'm trying to get all sites and foreach site, count of stats for the connected user.

For the moment i tried :

```
//repository
function getAll($user_id = 0)
{

    $with = [];

    $with['users'] = function ($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('id', '=', $user_id);
    };
    return Site::with($with)->orderBy('name')->get();
}
//controller
$sites = getAll($user_id);

//view
foreach($sites as $site){
  $count_stats = $site->users->first()->stats->where('site_id',$site->id)->count();
}
```

It works but it is not very elegant, it does a lot of sql requests and the page is slower.

**Do you have a better solution ?**

Comment: It does not the best solution to use Where in view.

Comment: Aggregates are probably what you want here, so that the math is done DB side: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates

Comment: @Yurich I'm totally agree ^^
ihatehandles It is exactly what i used no ?

Comment: [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) will be very helpful to analyze the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 0):

If Sites have many Users, and Sites have many Stats, then a User *has many Stats through Site*

Modify `User` class:

```
public function stats() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Stat', 'App\Site', 'user_id', 'site_id');
}
```

Eager load:

```
$user = User::with('stats')->find($user_id);
$stats = $user->stats();
```

Also, I think your Stat should `belongsTo` Site, since Site `hasMany` Stat. You need to change a lot of the `belongsToMany` as well since they look incorrectly used.

Comment: But users have many site too so hasManyThrough doesn't work. I edited my question to precise relationships. Nevertheless, you're right for the incorrect hasOne, i replaced it by a belongTo.